# How do large teams manage their changelog

Tags: operation, changelog

Using commit messages for changelogs is obviously terrible, and the suggested method from  https://keepachangelog.com/ doesn't scale, but works well for smaller teams. Is there a library or a common way to handle changelogs for larger teams?

Comment: I've made a custom solution as it isn't that complicated, others may want to look at gitlabs changelog solution